# Not able to start Jetty in pre-integration-test phase

Tags: java, maven, selenium, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I would like that Jetty is started before integrations tests, so that I could run my Selenium integration tests against my webapp. However, when I run `mvn verify` Jetty is not started and Selenium tests naturally fails. Any ideas what is wrong?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.0.M1</version>
    <configuration>
        <webApp>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        </webApp>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unit-tests</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `maven-surefire-plugin` which run unit tests. But in your case, you want to run integration tests.

You have to use the [maven-fail-safeplugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) in order to run integration tests. This plugin has two goals: `integration-test` & `verify`, integrated in the maven lifecycle:

- `pre-integration-test`
- `integration-test`
- `post-integration-test`
- `verify`

So in your case use something like:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>integration-test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <configuration>
     ...
    </configuration>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried also this but with same result - integration test will start but Jetty will not.

Comment: Could you share the console output ?

Answer (score 0):

I cant see anything wrong with your `jetty-maven-plugin` configuration but how do you handle the Selenium Configuration? Do you have a plugin configuration in that direction?:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${your.selenium.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-selenium</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start-server</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <background>true</background>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-selenium</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop-server</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then make sure to have the same port for your Jetty server as for your Selenium Testcases (Selenium uses 4444 as default port), e.g. either the default port of 8080 or another port configured with `<port>xy</port>` in the jetty plugin. In case of the default port it would look something like this:

```
new DefaultSelenium(“localhost”,4444,“*firefox”,“http://localhost:8080″);
```

Comment: I'm not using Selenium plugin. Browser starts and navigates to exactly right address and uses the right port, but there is no application running because starting Jetty fails.

Comment: Alright in that case youre obviously not missing a Selenium plugin configuration :) By "because starting Jetty fails" i assume youre not talking about actual excpetions or build failures but rather of the state of the server not beeing startet - I recomend to add the relevant part of the pre-/post-integration-test phases to the question. (I fear i wont be a help any further but will defently check back).